# FFmpeg apply multiple filters (Logo overlay, Brightness change and text overlay)

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I am trying to add three filters to a png file using ffmpeg in Android (I am using the writing mind lib).

**So far I managed to pull together the cmd:**

```
-i /storage/emulated/0/videoApp/temp/firstFrameOfMergedVideo.png 

-i /storage/emulated/0/videoApp/temp/logo.png

-filter_complex
```

### FIRST FILTER

```
[1:v]scale=h=-1:w=100[overlay_scaled],[0:v][overlay_scaled]overlay=eval=init:x=W-100-W*0.1:y=W*0.1,
```

### SECOND FILTER

```
drawtext=fontfile=/system/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf:text='xbsg':fontcolor=white:fontsize=60:box=1:boxcolor=0x7FFFD4@0.5:boxborderw=20:x=20:y=h-(text_h*2)-(h*0.1):enable='between(t,0,2)',
```

### THIRD FILTER

```
drawtext=fontfile=/system/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf:text='cbeh':fontcolor=white:fontsize=30:box=1:boxcolor=0x7FFFD4@0.5:boxborderw=20:x=20:y=h-text_h-(h*0.1)+25:enable='between(t,0,2)',
```

### FOURTH FILTER

```
eq=contrast=1:brightness=0.26180276:saturation=1:gamma=1:gamma_r=1:gamma_g=1:gamma_b=1:gamma_weight=1 
-c:a
copy
/storage/emulated/0/videoApp/temp/frameWithFilters.png
```

Right now I am trying to separate the filters using `,` but I also tried `;`

**It throws me back:**

```
Input #0, png_pipe, from '/storage/emulated/0/videoApp/temp/firstFrameOfMergedVideo.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 1080x1920, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc

Input #1, png_pipe, from '/storage/emulated/0/videoApp/temp/logo.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 528x582, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc

[NULL @ 0xf265d800] Unable to find a suitable output format for ','
,: Invalid argument
```

If I apply them individual they work.

I am new to ffmpeg so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your command should work (using the commas to link your [simple filters](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Simple-filtergraphs)) unscripted in a command-line environment, so it's not a problem with ffmpeg. Probably the typical quoting issue experienced by Android users trying to use ffmpeg. Unrelated to the issue, but you don't need `-c:a copy` since your inputs are PNG.

Comment: I verify it was a format issue, the command also itself was not correct as I had to make some stream vars, so the correct stream got the brightness change and the overlays remained unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

The filters must pass in the String array as one string
For example filterArray[2] = "-filter_complex" filterArray[3] ="rest of filter".

If anyone is curious the following piece of code applies up to three filters, if present to a video. These filters can be a change of brightness ( needs to be applied first so other filters can be applied on top ), an overlay of a logo image placed at the top right corner and scaled down to a specific size and two text overlays placed one below the other at the bottom left corner.

```
public void applyFiltersToImage(String srcPath, String outPath, String logoPath, String name, String function, float brightness, ProgressListener progressListener) {

    List<String> cmdList = new ArrayList<>();
    cmdList.add("-i");
    cmdList.add(srcPath);
    if (logoPath != null) {
        cmdList.add("-i");
        cmdList.add(logoPath);
    }

    cmdList.add("-filter_complex");

    StringBuilder filterBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    if (brightness != 0) {
        filterBuilder
                .append("eq=contrast=1:brightness=")
                .append(brightness)
                .append(":saturation=1:gamma=1:gamma_r=1:gamma_g=1:gamma_b=1:gamma_weight=1[v]");
        if (logoPath != null || name != null || function != null)
            filterBuilder.append(";");
    }


    if (logoPath != null) {

        filterBuilder
                .append("[1:v]scale=h=-1:w=")
                .append("100")
                .append("[overlay_scaled],")
                .append(brightness != 0 ? "[v]" : "[0:v]")
                .append("[overlay_scaled]overlay=eval=init:x=W-")
                .append("100")
                .append("-W*0.1:y=W*0.1[v]");

        if (name != null || function != null)
            filterBuilder.append(";[v]");
    }

    if (name != null || function != null) {
        if(brightness != 0 && logoPath == null)
            filterBuilder.append("[v]");

        filterBuilder
                .append("drawtext=fontfile=")
                .append("/system/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf")
                .append(":text='")
                .append(name)
                .append("':fontcolor=white:fontsize=")
                .append("60")
                .append(":box=1:boxcolor=0x7FFFD4@0.5:boxborderw=20:x=20:y=h-(text_h*2)-(h*0.1):enable=\'between(t,0,2)\'")
                .append(",drawtext=fontfile=")
                .append("/system/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf")
                .append(":text='")
                .append(function)
                .append("':fontcolor=white:fontsize=")
                .append("30")
                .append(":box=1:boxcolor=0x7FFFD4@0.5:boxborderw=20:x=20:y=h-text_h-(h*0.1)+25:enable=\'between(t,0,2)\'[v]");
    }

    cmdList.add(filterBuilder.toString());
    cmdList.add("-map");
    cmdList.add("[v]");
    cmdList.add(outPath);

    String[] cmd = new String[cmdList.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < cmdList.size(); i++) {
        cmd[i] = cmdList.get(i);
    }

    executeCmd(cmd, progressListener, outPath);
}
```